# YEARLY RRULE interpretation when more than one of BYMONTH, BYWEEKNO, BYYEARDAY are present

Tags: icalendar, rrule

I am currently struggling with an interpretation detail of RFC 5545.  [Section 3.3.10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10) states that essentially, all `BYxxx` fields show an *expanding* behavior, except for `BYDAY`, which has specific rules depending on which `BYxxx` fields are actually present.

However, it is unclear to me what exactly is supposed to happen for an `RRULE` that specifies *more than one* of {`BYMONTH`, `BYWEEKNO`, `BYYEARDAY`}. In my opinion the table in Section 3.3.10 allows for the interpretation that I have to *expand* every rule part separately, that is, to build the union of the three sets resulting from

1. Expanding `BYMONTH`, `BYMONTHDAY` etc.
2. Expanding `BYWEEKNO`
3. Expanding `BYYEARDAY`

all the while honoring Note 2 that explains the `BYDAY` behavior. The result can be somewhat counter-intuitive (and of course it is fairly unlikely that users would specify such rules). But there is at least one implementation out there that [claims to do it this way](https://ewsoftware.github.io/PDI/html/3f7e1bcc-3afe-4978-95e7-e6515eae45df.htm#YearlyFreq):

> For the `YEARLY` frequency, the `BYMONTH`, `BYWEEKNO`, and `BYYEARDAY` rules are expanded separately from each other if specified.

Other implementations, such as http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/ or Google Calendar, appear to use a *limiting* strategy if more than one of the rule parts are present:

1. Expand `BYMONTH`/`BYMONTHDAY`
2. Then limit using `BYWEEKNO` and `BYYEARDAY`

effeectively creating an intersection rather than a union.  That approach seems somewhat consistent with the *application order* for the rule parts stipulated by Section 3.3.10:

> If multiple `BYxxx` rule parts are specified, then after evaluating
> the specified `FREQ` and `INTERVAL` rule parts, the `BYxxx` rule parts
> are applied to the current set of evaluated occurrences in the
> following order: `BYMONTH`, `BYWEEKNO`, `BYYEARDAY`, `BYMONTHDAY`, `BYDAY`,
> `BYHOUR`, `BYMINUTE`, `BYSECOND` and `BYSETPOS`; then `COUNT` and `UNTIL` are
> evaluated.

However, interpreting this to mean that the rule parts are *limiting* rather than *expanding* appears to me to be in direct contradiction of the expand/limit table shown on [page 44 of the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#page-44).

My question thus is:

**Does RFC5545 actually unambiguously specify how the simultaneous presence of more than one of `BYMONTH`, `BYWEEKNO` and `BYYEARDAY` is to be interpreted? If so, where does it state it?** And if the standard is actually unclear in this regard, is there a “de-facto standard” preferred way of dealing with this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does RFC5545 actually unambiguously specify how the simultaneous presence of more than one of BYMONTH, BYWEEKNO and BYYEARDAY is to be interpreted?

Well yes, in the excerpt you quoted in your question: they are applied **to the current set of evaluated occurrences** in order.

The term **current set of evaluated occurrences** is the key part of the sentence. For example let's take a rule with BYMONTH and BYYEARDAY.

1. BYMONTH is evaluated first, generating a set of occurrences (*expanding* on the YEARLY frequency, i.e. more than one occurrence per year can be in the set)
2. only *then* BYYEARDAY is applied on **those occurrences only**, i.e. the occurrences that matches BYMONTH. Every year day that does not match BYMONTH is not considered, because it is not, by definition, part of the current set of occurrences calculated in step 1.

The expand/limit table is irrelevant in this case. The RFC states very clearly:

> "The table below summarizes the dependency of BYxxx rule part expand or limit behavior **on the FREQ rule part value.**"

The table does *not* summarizes the behavior of BYxxx rule part *on other BYxxx rule parts*.

Therefore it is unambiguously an intersection. Think about it that way: if the result was a union, there would be no way to write rules such as "every day of the 5th week of the year that are in February" (`FREQ=YEARLY;BYWEEKNO=5;BYMONTH=2`).

To achieve a *union*, the RFC defines a *recurrence set*, which is simply combining multiple RRULE, RDATE and EXDATE (though for some reason the RFC states that RRULE *should not* appear more than once).

> And if the standard is actually unclear in this regard, is there a “de-facto standard” preferred way of dealing with this situation?

I am the maintainer of [php-rrule](https://github.com/rlanvin/php-rrule) which is a port of Python [dateutil](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil) and this is how both version handle this situation. As far as I remember, Javascript and Ruby libraries also work this way. I don't know about every other libraries that is out there, but the RFC is quite clear anyway, as I hope I have demonstrated above.

#### Edit: answer to your comment about BYDAY

The Note 2 of the table can be indeed quite confusing, so here is a little clarification. `BYDAY` is special because it has 2 syntaxes: the simple one with the name of the day (e.g. `MO`, `TU` and so on) and the "complicated" one with the name of the day *and* the position in the set. For example `1MO` means "the first Monday" and `-1MO` "the last Monday". However the question is "the first/last Monday of *what*?".

- When using a YEARLY frequency and `BYDAY=1MO,2MO`, it is "the first and the second Monday of the year", when using MONTHLY it is "the first and the second Monday of the month" and so on, this is pretty straightforward.
- However when using a YEARLY frequency *and* `BYMONTH=2,3` for example then the rule actually means "every February and March" so the question is: should you get every first and second Monday of February and March (expand), or every first and second Monday *of the year* that occur in February and March - i.e. empty set, since both are in January (limit). The answer is to do a "special expand" by actually treating it as a "MONTHLY" frequency (even if it is YEARLY) and therefore the meaning of `BYDAY=1MO,2MO` changes to "every first and second Monday of February AND every first and second Monday of March`.

Quote relevant part of the RFC

> The numeric value in a
>        BYDAY rule part with the FREQ rule part set to YEARLY corresponds
>        to an offset within the month when the BYMONTH rule part is
>        present, and corresponds to an offset within the year when the
>        BYWEEKNO or BYMONTH rule parts are present.

To be perfectly honest I'm not sure why there is this special case for BYDAY, but in any case it's quite clear how it should behave.

Comment: Thanks very much, that makes sense and is as I expected. Your counterexample for the _union_ hypothesis is exactly the kind of case that made me ask this question. My confusion stemmed from the fact that the `BYDAY` part _does_ expand other `BYxxx` parts according to Note 2 on the table while the other `BYxxx` parts actually have more of a limiting behavior. That was the result of me concentrating on the table too much. Thanks for pointing out the key phrase.

Comment: @mindriot No worries, glad I could help. I wanted to answer your comment about BYDAY but it was a bit too long for a comment, so I edited my answer. BYDAY is indeed a special case that is treated slightly differently.

Comment: One more question though: What part of the spec allows you to conclude that `FREQ=YEARLY;BYWEEKNO=5;BYMONTH=2` contains _all_ the days falling in week 5 and February? From the [spec on page 43](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#page-43), 2nd-to-last paragraph, I would expect the day (and time) to be taken from `DTSTART` since the week number doesn't clearly determine the actual day. I can't find anything to indicate that we must expand to _all_ days in this case. Indeed, while Google and dateutil expand to all days, Thunderbird Lightning for example does not.

Comment: By the way, a minor point regarding your last quote: https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=5545&eid=1913

Comment: @mindriot The RFC is unclear about exactly what information should be extracted from `DTSTART` and in what case, and this is admittedly open to interpretation. My reasoning is the same as for your original question: if it didn't contain *all* the days of the week, how else would you write a rule to match "all days of week X"?

Comment: for example, by explicitly adding all weekdays to the `BYDAY` rule. Otherwise you could argue that _all_ hours etc. should also added - why limit it to `BYDAY`? Nevertheless, I prefer your interpretation as it leads to more compact rule expressions.

Comment: @mindriot You are considering `BYDAY`, but what about `BYMONTHDAY` (e.g. *4th* of Jan)? Should it also be extracted from the `DTSTART`? Should you also have to add all the month days (1 to 31) to the rule? And what about the month itself (e.g. Jan), should it also be extracted from `DTSTART`? Ofc, you are right, one could argue the opposite - why only expand days, and not hours, minutes, seconds? As I said, this part of the RFC is open to interpretation, and one only try to infer what the authors had in mind from the examples at the end of the RFC and implement what makes the most sense.

Comment: I agree, the “sanest” interpretation seems to be that only `BYWEEKNO` should get a somewhat special treatment in that it expands to all weekdays. (Mind you, `BYMONTHDAY` is indeed initialized from `DTSTART` for `FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=x`.)
Thanks again for your help.